# Why System.out.printf will only work with %f when all of the variables are declared as double?

Tags: java

Here is my program.  Just a little one for end of chapter exercises. Problem is that when I run it, it only works when I have %f in my System.printf when in my mind it should be a %d. All of my variables are double and Math.ceil returns a double so I am super confused.  Could someone clarify please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excersise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double enteredHours = 0;
        double amountDue = 0;

        System.out.printf("Please enter the number of hours parked.");
        enteredHours = input.nextDouble();

        amountDue = calculateCharges(enteredHours);
        System.out.printf("The amount due is %f\n", amountDue); // HERE the line
                                                                // that when I
                                                                // changed it to
                                                                // %f it works,
                                                                // but again all
                                                                // variables are
                                                                // double and
                                                                // Math.ceil
                                                                // returns a
                                                                // double.

    }

    public static double calculateCharges(double hours) {

        double roundedHours = 0;
        roundedHours = Math.ceil(hours);
        double charges = 2.00;

        if (roundedHours > 3.0)
            charges = charges + .5 * roundedHours;
        if (roundedHours >= 24.0)
            charges = 10.00;

        return charges;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html Because `%d` means "a decimal integer"?

Comment: The `d` in `%d` is for _decimal_.  This is because there are several ways of formatting integers, including `%o` for octal and `%x` for hexadecimal (don't ask me why it isn't `%h`, this decision was made over 40 years ago by the original C designers).

Comment: Yeah this is what confused me, its a "decimal integer." I did think of d for decimal but integers by definition are whole number with no decimal numbers...so I was thinking d is for double.  Not sure why they named it that way.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

%d is to format an 'integer' %f is for formatting floats/doubles. I think you're mistaking '%d' to stand for double

Comment: yep you were right.  The book i have says %d stand for decimal integer...guess I forgot about that integer part and was just thinking decmial ie double.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

%f is the format specifier for floating point variables whereas %d is used for integer variables.

Answer (score 0):

`%f` is used for formatting floats/double and %d is used for decimal and In java `%d` is used for display the result for example :-

```
public class Exercise 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    long number = 30208;
    System.out.printf("Number: %d", + number);
}
}
```

here we use `%d` for display the value of long variable